# Do I need any special equipment to make my circuit run off power from a phone/laptop charger?

Tags: dc, safety, charger, battery-operated

Is it safe for one to replace a 5v battery source with a phone charger without installing any other components to prevent power surges or injury to any people in contact with the device? Also, is it safe to use a phone charger to run components like LEDs as if the charger were a battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, proper CE/UL marked phone chargers should have short circuit protection and mains isolation of their own.

Comment: So, practically, a phone charger may be used as a battery eliminator right?

Comment: Yes. Although if there are other power sources in the circuit or other connections to ground, watch out for ground loops.

Comment: sorry for asking so many questions but I was just wondering if it was safe to run an electromagnet on such a circuit as it may damage the supply (short circuit)

Comment: Depends on the current draw. A fuse or polyfuse is always a good idea.

Comment: Laptop chargers can be different. I've seen some where the ground on the DC side is connected to the ground on the AC side, which may not be a good idea for whatever it is you're doing. You can check with a ohmmeter.